# Git: show only differences introduced in feature branch

Tags: git

At some point in our codebase, a new feature branch (FEAT-123) was created off of DEV

Throughout it's development cycle, DEV was merged into the feature branch so that it stayed up to date with what other devs were working on.

Eventually, the feature was completed and FEAT-123 was merged into DEV.

e.g.

```
FEAT-123     ---------
            /   /     \
DEV      -------------------
```

Now, I'm working on a very similar feature, and it would be incredibly convenient to be able to see only the changes introduced *by* the FEAT-123 branch. Is there a git command to accomplish that?

(note: We tag every commit with the feature branch it was created for, so I can find them in the log by hand. If I need to manually invoke every commit ID, that's possible tho obviously not preferable)

Comment: You mean like `git diff`?

Comment: A little more complex than a standard diff since everything was merged together months ago. No two commits that I could diff between will contain all the changes I need to know and only those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git works off snapshots, if you don't have the right series of snapshots for any purpose, construct them. Finding the *oldest* merge base of two first-parent histories is an easy enough request,

```
oldestbase=$(
        (git rev-list --first-parent DEV; git rev-list --first-parent FEAT-123) \
        | awk 'seen[$0]++ {print;exit}'
)
```

so assuming nothing else was merged into `FEAT-123` you just `cherry-pick -n` the non-merge commits in its first-parent ancestry back to that oldest branch point, something very close to:

```
git checkout $oldestbase
git cherry-pick -n $(git rev-list --reverse --first-parent --no-merges ..FEAT-123)
git diff @
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I have to review the diff I ended up with to be sure it's got the changes I need, but I think that may be the answer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout `dev` at the commit before the merge and then `diff` to the feature branch.

Comment: That would show the contents of other branches that had been merged into dev and subsequently merged into FEAT-123

Comment: It would show what merging FEAT-123 into develop would do and that's what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

```
FEAT-123     --------T
            /   /     \
DEV      --------------M----
```

1. Find the commit `M` that merged `FEAT-123` into `DEV`.
2. This commit probably has two parents, one of which was the tip of `FEAT-123` back when that merge happened. Identify which one. (Let's call it `T`).
3. `git diff T..M`

Answer (score 0):

```
FEAT-123     --------T
            /   /     \
DEV      --X---Y------------
```

With commit named as above : getting the diff between `Y` and `T` -- which would display all the changes brought by `FEAT-123` when it was merged in `DEV` -- is simply :

```
git diff DEV...T   #  3 dots
```